# VBA Excel Insert "password" in Popup box

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro that refreshes a certain workbook that I get information from frequently. Long story short the macro works but the workbook I am opening has a popup for a password. Is there a function I can use to insert the password in the popup so I do not have to?

note: yes I know this is insecure but the document doesn't contain sensitive data, the password is stupid simple and would be circumvented in less than 10 sec by any good password cracker.

Comment: if you open workbook with `Workbooks.Open` method then there are parameters which allow to include password. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194819%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you describe:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Hello.xls", Password:="OpenSesame"
```

(obviously you will have to change that to reflect your situation)